# python - Accessing superclass's class attribute in super().__init__()

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have a class `Parent` with many instance properties, and I always pass a `dict` to initialize an instance. Like this:

```
info = {
    "name" : "Bob",
    "col" : 5,
    "line" : 10,
    "type" : "Alien"
}

p = Parent(info)
```

And in `__init__` method I don't want to write `this.property_name = value` for each property cuz the code will be very long. For instance:

```
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self, kwargs):
        this.name = kwargs.get("name")
        this.col = kwargs.get("col")
        this.line = kwargs.get("line")
        this.type = kwargs.get("type")
```

So I want to use a function to iterate the `dict` to set these instance properties. This is the function I wrote:

```
def initialize_properties(instance, names, kwargs):
    for name in names:
        setattr(instance, name, kwargs.get(name))
```

It seems that I need to store the property name list `names` somewhere, and I decide to store it as a class attribute, because I want my class to be **human friendly** (when somebody reads the class definition he knows what instance properties this class has). So I changed my class definition as follows:

```
class Parent(object):
    props = ("name", "col", "line", "type")

    def __init__(self, kwargs):
        initialize_properties(self, self.props, kwargs)
```

This works fine when inheritance is NOT considered. The problem occurs when I subclass `Parent`:

```
class Child(Parent):
    props = ("foo", "bar")

    def __init__(self, kwargs):
        super().__init__(kwargs)
        initialize_properties(self, self.props, kwargs)
```

I want instances of `Child` to inherit all the instance properties in superclass `Parent`, with some child-specific instance properties as well.(This is why we use inheritance, isn't it?) So I overwrite the class attribute `props` to define child-specific properties.

But it doesn't work.

```
info = {
    "name" : "Bob",
    "col" : 5,
    "line" : 10,
    "type" : "Alien",
    "foo" : 5,
    "bar" : 10
}

c = Child(info)
```

Instance `c` only has `c.foo` and `c.bar` defined and set, while `c.name` is not defined.

After some digging I found that when `Parent.__init__(self, kwargs)` is called through the `super()` function, the `self` argument passed is of class `Child`, so `self.props` evaluates to `Child.props`.

If I want to set the instance properties in `Parent.props`, I have to explicitly use `Parent.props` in `Parent.__init__(self, kwargs)`, which is:

```
class Parent(object):
    props = ("name", "col", "line", "type")

    def __init__(self, kwargs):
        initialize_properties(self, Parent.props, kwargs)
```

This will solve the problem, but I think it's not very "clean" because you have to hard-code the class name `Parent`.

So my question is: Is there any way to **detect the current class and access its class attributes, when you are calling a chain of `super().__init__()` to initialize an subclass instance?**

Comment: This seems like a lot of work to avoid `this.property_name = value` "for each property cuz the code will be very long" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a method that collects the `props` from all supeclasses and use it in the `__init__`:

```
class Parent(object):
    props = ("name", "col", "line", "type")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        def __init__(self, kwargs):
        initialize_properties(self, self.get_props(), kwargs)

    def get_props(self):
        return sum((getattr(k, 'props', ()) for k in self.__class__.mro()), ())
```

Now, you can simply define subclasses the way you wanted. You wouldn't even have to override the constructor:

```
class Child(Parent):
    props = ("foo", "bar")
```

That being said, you claim you want your classes **human friendly**. If a human reads your child class, they will be glad to read:

```
class Child(Parent):
    props = 'foo', 'bar', 'name', 'col', 'line', 'type'
```

and have all the class' `props` available in one place.

Answer (score 1):

`self.props` first references instance attribute, then class attribute, and parents' class attribute, ...

By defining `Child.props`, `self.props` refers `Child.props` class attribute, stopping there, not searching in parent class.

How about make the `Child.props` also include parents' `props`?

```
class Child(Parent):
    props = Parent.props + ("foo", "bar")   # <---

    def __init__(self, kwargs):
        super().__init__(kwargs)
        initialize_properties(self, self.props, kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question

> Is there any way to detect the current class and access its class
>   attributes, when you are calling a chain of super().**init**()

In my opinion, no way.

However, you can use decorator to simplify your code

```
def add_props(names, cls=None):
    if cls is None:
        return lambda cls:add(names, cls)
    for c in cls.__bases__:
        names.extend(c.props)
    names = list(set(names))
    cls.props = names
    return cls


class A:
    props = ['a','b']


@add_props(names=['c'])
class B(A):
    pass
```

output:

```
In [69]: B.props
Out[69]: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

But, it must said that if you want  human friendly, the best way i think is not using `props`, just write code in your `__init__` method.

```
class Root:
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


class Child(Root):
    def __init__(self, c=None, d=None, **kwargs):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

You can also have convenience to pass dict as you like

```
data = {'a': 1}
c = Child(**data)
```

And it is not only friendly  to human but also friendly to most editors.